# How to set opacity in drawing lines use three.js, use LineBasicMaterial?

Tags: three.js

I want to change lines' width and opacity,and my code as this:

```
 var geometry_link = new THREE.Geometry();
 geometry_link.vertices.push(
 new THREE.Vector3(item[0].x *1,item[0].y *1,item[0].z),
 new THREE.Vector3(item[1].x *1,item[1].y *1,item[1].z)
 );
 geometry_link.colors.push(
 new THREE.Color(0x000000),
 new THREE.Color(0xffffff)
 );
 var line = new THREE.Line(geometry_link, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
     vertexColors: true,
     linewidth: 8,
     transparent: true,
     opacity: 0.1
})
```

but it dose not work, both linewidth and opacity. I have found the similar question,said linewidth does not work on windows, that's 5 years ago, how about now?
Thanks for your idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LineBasicMaterial` does support transparent lines as demonstrated by the following live example:

```js
let camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
  camera.position.z = 1;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints([new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0)]);
  const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.5
  });

  const mesh = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.119.1/build/three.js"></script>
```

Wide lines however are not supported. So setting `linewidth` to a different value like `1` has no effect in most browsers. This is a WebGL limitation in context of line primitives.

However, `three.js` provides a wide line implementation based on triangles (sometimes called mesh lines or ribbons). Check out the following example for more information:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lines_fat

Comment: Note that `transparent` has to be set initially to `true` if you want to change the opacity later, dynamically updating `transparent` seems to be unsupported.